# Keep section headings within a certain part of the line

Tags: titlesec, linewidth

Is it possible to force section headings to stay within the first 30% of the `\linewidth`? In other words, how can I make the section headings occupy a column whose width is 3/10 the width of the line? I would expect `titlesec` to be the package to do this with, but I don't know what to do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat
{\section}
{\Large}
{}
{0cm}
{}

\begin{document}

\section{A section whose name is so long that it will, if unchecked, undesirably spill into the latter seven-tenths of the width of the line}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could box the section title. What should happen to the rest of the line? Should it be empty?

Comment: @cfr Yes, empty.

Comment: @cfr Is it possible to use the box idea inside `\titleformat`? Or does every `\section` need to be boxed in "manually"?

Comment: It's probably possible. It certainly doesn't need to be done manually. However, it's better somebody else answer this because I'd do it without `titlesec`. There's nothing wrong with `titlesec` - everyone else likes it. I just don't get on with it for some reason.

Comment: @cfr, may be, for reference, you can answer by posting your non-titlesec approach? Would at least be interesting to know about.

Comment: @MS-SPO I didn't mean I have a solution. I meant, if I were doing this, I wouldn't use `titlesec`. I took a look in response to your comment, but I'd be reluctant to spend the time on this unless it was actually going to be useful! It's not easy to do this with the standard classes because of the way the sectioning commands work. I don't know to what extent it's possible to 'hook into' that system or if you'd need to recreate all the stuff that happens when a new section is started. You also have to account for all the cases ....